# Django model field default value same as PK

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, model

I have a django model with id as PK and another field called sub_user which I want by default to have the same value as the ID.How can I do that?

```
sub_user        = models.IntegerField(default= ? )
```

Comment: Please do *not* write foreign keys like that. Use a `ForeignKey`, such that it can check referential integrity.

Comment: You didn't answered my question.